# Keep track of changes to cell address in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have implemented my own custom audit trail because the built-in Excel Track Changes function doesn't cooperate with any macros that need to unprotect a sheet to edit a locked cell.

One problem is that a value could be entered into cell A1 for example. The audit trail will capture this appropriately. Then rows/columns can be inserted such that the value that was originally entered into A1 now lives in B1, A2, or anywhere else on the sheet. The audit trail will capture the fact that rows/columns were inserted, so you can technically follow the trail and figure out that the value currently in A54 was originally entered into A1, and 53 rows have since been inserted. However, it would be ideal if I could have both an "original range" field and a "current range" field in the audit trail that would show the value as being in A54, but originally entered into A1.

Is there a way to do this either with cell formulas or through VBA?

Comment: If you have existing code please include it in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered my own question

In the same code that adds the audit trail information, I also add two formulas to different columns. So in this case, column F holds the original Range, column H is assigned a formula with a relative reference to that range, and column G holds a formula for getting the formula of column H. That way, column F says essentially, "original value was entered into 'Sheet1'!A1", column G says "that cell is now 'Sheet1'!A54" and column H says "this is the value in 'Sheet1'!A54"

Note: the variable "audit" refers to the sheet that holds the audit trail. The variable "aRow" refers to the current row of the audit trail. The variable "active" refers to the name of the active sheet being edited.

```
Sheets(audit).Range("F" & aRow) = Target.Cells.Address(False, False)
Sheets(audit).Range("H" & aRow) = "=" & "'" & active & "'!" & Target.Address(False, False)
Sheets(audit).Range("G" & aRow) = "=FORMULATEXT(L" & last & ")"
```